# Dynamic Column Names in Crystal Report Header

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report-XI:

My report columns headings are in table which generate dynamically and i want to print in report header area. let say,

I have a table (MyTable) contain columns (id,value) and three rows. I want to print specific value in report header based on condition. like for column2 i need value "SELECT Value FROM MyTable WHERE Id=2" so "Heading-2" should be printed in report header similarly for rest columns.

Note:condition for a heading (WHERE Id=2) can be fixed since I need to print value as a heading .

I tried to make formula but this formula always show first value.

**MyTable**

```
==========================================
|  Id   |     Value
==========================================
|   1   |     Heading-1
|   2   |     Heading-2
|   3   |     Heading-3
==========================================
```

Comment: how is your report structure?

Comment: @Siva structure is same like Header, Detail, Footer simple report but columns name are dynamics cannot fixed. so like column1 can be formula field,